# Результат запроса mysql возвращает тип только Byte

Tags: mysql, база-данных, vb.net

Суть проблемы: ответ на запрос к внешней базе данных возвращает тип данных Byte. Однако при отправке точно такого же запроса к другой внешней базе ответ приходит нормально. Возможно конечно проблема в настройках серверов мускул. Но как ее решить не трогая настройки на сервере? 
Кусок кода из функции ниже:

```
connect.Open()
comm.Connection = connect
comm.CommandText = queryFullstring
reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read()
    series.Text = reader.GetValue(0)
End While
reader.Close()
connect.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем не знаю в этом ли дело было. Вместо индекса колонки задал ее имя и все заработало!

```
        While reader.Read()
            series.Text += reader.GetChar("series")
        End While
```